# Change frames in Java, Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, dispose, frames

I made a project in Java (Netbeans). I have a lot of frames, and when i want to change frame, i use this code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    dispose();
    Opt p_b = new Opt();
    p_b.setVisible(true);
}
```

But, i do not want to see when a frame closes and one other opens. I want to open all frames, in the same window. Do you understand me or did I not describe well? Can you help me? Or give me an example?

Comment: Maybe you need to use [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) inside main Frame? In this case you will have one Window(`JFrame`) and some `JInternalFrame` inside it

Comment: Thank you but it does not exactly what i want !

Answer (score 1):

use one JFrame that has multiple JPanels; and switch between JPanels (using **CardLayout**).

[check Oracle link it has a lot of examples about layouts managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Thank you,but at the begin says :  This lesson covers writing layout code by hand, which can be challenging. I made the design by hand,just choose the buttons,labels etc and put into frame. So,the code is ready from Netbeans and i can not change it ! :/

Comment: then change your code to:
    Opt p_b = new Opt();
    p_b.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
make the new one visible before disposing the one that is already visible

Answer (score 0):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    setVisible(true);
    dispose();
    Opt p_b = new Opt();
    p_b.setVisible(true);
}
```

Have the `setVisible(true);` at the beginning of your code, so every window will remain open.